# Change Fa Icon On Click

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://codepen.io/LukzzXB/pen/xNwwJL

im pretty much trying to get the two icons (fa volume up) (fa volume mute) to switch between the two when pressed
i can get the two icons to be over each other
but i believe i need to javascript to do this
i tried to use "toggle" function etc but having a bit of trouble
thanks

```
<a href="#noscroll" id="mute"><i class="fas fa-volume-up fa-3x"></a></i>
        <a href="#noscroll"id="unmute"><i class="fas fa-volume-off fa-3x"></a></i>
```

so I'm pretty much trying get the icon to change onclick.

Comment: Not sure you noticed, your HTML tags are not matching..  `<a><i></a></i>` is incorrect, `<a><i></i></a>` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

First, get elements and create variable to know if mute or unmute is displayed

```
var mute = document.getElementById("mute");
var unmute = document.getElementById("unmute");
var isMute = false;
```

create function to change apparence;

```
function toggleMute() {
    // inverse boolean
    isMute = !isMute;
    if (isMute) {
        mute.style.display = "none";
        unmute.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        mute.style.display = "block";
        unmute.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

and add events listener

```
mute.addeventListener("click", toggleMute);
unmute.addeventListener("click", toggleMute);
```

If you use font awesome, you can try to create only one element and change class when click.

EDIT

by default, in css, you need to set unmute in display none

EDIT 2

To mute or unmute audio, you can use [pause function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_audio_pause.asp).

Comment: This is good, but its just that as i said my inital id actually mutes an audio player and you just sort of took it out, so it would interfere

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having 2 links, just have the one and toggle the classes.

Below is a simple example..

```js
const muter = document.querySelector("#muter");

muter.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  ["fa-volume-up", "fa-volume-off"].forEach(
    c => e.target.classList.toggle(c));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a href="#noscroll" id="muter">
  <i class="fas fa-volume-up fa-3x"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: This is good, but its just that as i said my inital id actually mutes an audio player and you just sort of took it out, so it would interfere